# I want to add all the values in the field Sum to the field Total but it is not working

Tags: javascript, html

Here, sums[i].value is getting right values but when I want to keep a grand total of all   Sum, it is failing.

```
function calc() {
        var amounts = document.getElementsByName("Amount");
        var prices = document.getElementsByName("Price");
        var sums = document.getElementsByName('Sum');
        var tax = document.getElementsByName('Tax');
        var total = document.getElementsByName('Total');

        for (var i = 0; i < amounts.length; i++) {
            sums[i].value = amounts[i].value * prices[i].value;
            total[0].value = total[0].value + sums[i].value;
            // only this line is not working
        }

    }
```

Comment: Why don't you store the total in a variable and then assign to that Total element !

Comment: use parseInt(total[0].value) + parseInt(sums[i].value)

Comment: if the values in the field Sum are 4 , 10 and 6


then in total[0].value it shows 44104106

Comment: For best results, describe the problem in detail. "_it is failing_" and "_Not working_" do not provide enough information for us to provide a useful response. _What_ is failing, and how? What do you expect to happen and what is really happening?

Answer (score 1):

Plain HTML is strings, all the way down, and `var amounts = document.getElementsByName("Amount");` followed by `amounts.value` means you now have string values. Since `+` is also a string operator, JavaScript will happily turn `"2"+"4"` into "24", which looks like it did maths, but wrong, when in fact it didn't do math at all.

Convert all values that need to be numbers into numbers, first:

```
var amounts = document.getElementsByName("Amount");
....
var amount = parseFloat(amounts.value); // NOW it's a number
...
```

Comment: ok...but sums[i].value = amounts[i].value * prices[i].value;
is working perfect.

That means it is reading the numbers and doing the multiplication correct.

Comment: yes, because `*` is only defined for numbers, so if it sees `string * number` it convert the first string into a number (if it can) before applying `*`. So `sums` will work, but `totals` will fail because `string + number` gets that number turned into a string so that `+` will work, rather than throw an error (JavaScript can't add strings and numbers, so it has to convert them either both to numbr, or both to string). In your case it goes "the only way this'll work is to turn everything into strings, then apply the `+` operator". So if you need to work with numbers, force them to numbers first

Answer (score 0):

Replace your code with :

```
for (var i = 0; i < amounts.length; i++) {
    sums[i].value = parseFloat(amounts[i].value) * parseFloat(prices[i].value);
    total[0].value = parseFloat(total[0].value) + parseFloat(sums[i].value);
    // only this line is not working
}
```

Comment: Shows NaN in total[0].value

Comment: All the input should have value to work. If the value of length is 3 then there should be three `input` with `name` `total`. Are you sure about that?

Answer (score 0):

```
sums[i].value = parseFloat(amounts[i].value) * parseFloat(prices[i].value);
total[0].value = parseFloat(total[0].value) + parseFloat(sums[i].value);
```

This should help you.

Comment: Shows NaN in total[0].value

Comment: Make sure that all the input boxes are filled before calculation.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the .value while adding and multiplying

```
function test()
    {
var amounts = new Array();
amounts[0] = "4";
amounts[1] = "6";
amounts[2] = "10";
var prices = new Array();
prices[0] = "4";
prices[1] = "6";
prices[2] = "10";
      var sums = new Array();
      var total = 0;

        for (var i = 0; i < amounts.length; i++) {
              sums[i] = parseInt(amounts[i]) * parseInt(prices[i]);
              total= parseInt(total) + parseInt(sums[i]);
            // only this line is not working

//alert(total); is 152
           }
    }
```